# Is it necessary to use main method when we develop web application using spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am new to the Spring boot. I have been practicing Spring Boot with the standalone application in which I used the main method. since the Main method is the entry point. Now I am going to work with a Web application.

Moreover, We don't need to use the main method in servlet, struct and spring MVC for the web application.

Is it really necessary to use the main method in a spring boot web application?

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Example  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Example.class, args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Spring boot supports two modes of work:

- using embedded server (tomcat, jetty, whichever you choose). In this mode, you need a main method to start it
- using external sever. In this mode, you need to pack your project  into a war file, in the old fashion way. On this mode a main method is not required

Answer (score 4):

Method main is an entry point for standalone applications, so if you want to use spring boot standalone application, usually (if not always) packaged into a JAR - then yes, you should use main method.

If you work with Web Applications, however, they don't have main method.
The artifacts are Web Archives (have extension .WAR). Instead of "main" method you're supposed to create a `SpringBootServletInitializer` that will serve as an entry point of your WAR.

Having said that, the JAR is still the recommended way to go
See [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file) the example